# Flutter firebase expection not working properly ! Does't print the the error either ! (e)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

No matter what I try every try to run this flutter firebase exception it keeps running just the first message like it is not getting error codes, which I put in the 'try' but 'firebaseauthexception' catch doesn't run even tho I put wrong inputs.

```
Future passwordReset() async {
try{
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: emailController.text.trim());
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Password reset link has been sent to your email!'),
    ),
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Incorrect Email or Password'),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

I tries different methods with showDialog and showSnackBar still getting the same output.

Comment: If you remove the `on FirebaseAuthException`, does it raise/catch an error then?

Comment: Ensure that your Firebase authentication setup is correct and that Firebase is properly configured with your Flutter project. Incorrect configuration or missing dependencies could lead to unexpected behavior.